# Print Fit To Page

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, printdialog

I need to print a label to fit the page.
I'm tryng this but print big than page, width and height seems to be to much

```
private void PrinterPrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    var b = Tasks.Pop();

    if (b.Label == null) 
        b.Label = GetLabelImage(b.Codice, b.ColoreID);

    var rect = e.PageBounds;
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(b.Label, rect);
    e.HasMorePages = Tasks.ContainTasks();

    _printedCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [MSDNs documentation on PrintPageEventArgs.PageBounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs.pagebounds.aspx),

> Most printers cannot print at the very edge of the page.

...first of all, try changing `PageBounds` to `MarginBounds`.  If this doesn't help, "deflate" the bounds rectangle towards the centre of the page so you move away from the edges.

Comment: MarginBounds print in a ridiculus small area. this means that I will get a different result for each printer... bud thing. thanks aniway